# Parse.com beforeSave get dirty values

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

On the parse.com info log are the keys and values of the update visible:
[image: parse.com info log]
This is valid JSON, see

```
{
    "original": {
        "countReplies": 0,
        "owner": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "OKjocXCfUR"
        },
        "rating": 0,
        "message": "affdgf",
        "objectId": "7Rdu6ZWugr",
        "createdAt": "2015-02-03T11:57:06.523Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-02-03T11:57:06.523Z"
    },
    "update": {
        "rating": -1
    }
}
```

How can I access the "update" object from the request in beforeSave?
Here are some attempts without success:

```
console.log("1. update: " + request.object.dirtyKeys());
console.log("2. original: " + JSON.stringify(request.object));
console.log("3. rating original: " + request.object.get("rating"));
console.log("4. isDirty: " + request.get("update"));
console.log("5. " + request.object.get("update"));
console.log("6. " + update.get("rating"));
console.log("7. " + request.get("Input"));
```

Comment: Well... More details needed... what is `request` ? `request` is not some standard thing... it depends totally on JS framewrok.... which JS framewrok are you using...? Lets say we assume `express` then which middlewares are being used.

Comment: It is parse.com, see the title. It is a BaaS. I think they are using node.js with mongo db and the cloude code extends express.js

Comment: You need to make a query to get the old one.

Answer (score 0):

`Update` is neither a property of `request.object` or `dirtyKeys()`, it is simply the JSON being passed to the server. By the time you have reached function level it has already been interpreted by the [SDK](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html).

> Array of string **dirtyKeys( )** Returns an array of keys that have been
>   modified since last save/refresh
>
> Returns: Array of string

Your request object **IS** the updated version of the object. This is what the SDK is comparing to the database to determine which keys are dirty.

So, your updates are simply in the `request.object`

```
request.object.get("rating");
```